# PostgreSQL Format Timestamp with Timezone Offset (Australia/Sydney) as JSON/String

Tags: postgresql, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone, to-char, to-json

I would like to get a JSON object in Postgres that display timestamp with Australia/Sydney timezone offset (+10:00 or +11:00 during daylight saving), for example I would like json object returned with following values:

```
"2021-07-31T23:59:59.123456+10:00"   
"2021-01-31T23:59:59.123456+11:00"
```

But when I use either to_json() or to_char() the timestamp value returned is UTC with offset +00:00

```
select to_json(current_timestamp::timestamptz),
to_char(current_timestamp::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:MSOF')
```

"2021-01-31T07:47:22.895185+00:00"
2021-01-31T07:47:22:895+00

I have tried to add "at time zone 'AEDT'" but it shifts the timestamp value and keep the offset to +00:00.

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `current_timestamp::timestamptz` can be simplified to `current_timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_json` formats according to the current time zone setting of the session. I suggest that you [set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) the session time zone to `Australia/Sydney` first.

```sql
set time zone 'Australia/Sydney';
select to_json('2021-01-31T07:47:22.895+00'::timestamptz);
```

Yields 2021-01-31T18:47:22.895+11:00 which I guess is what you need.